# RSpec: how to test database fails when there's more database operations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, unit-testing, rspec

I have a method similar to this:

```
def create
  reservation = Reservation.create(params[:reservation_params])
  if reservation.valid?
    reserved_hour = ReservedHour.create(params[:reserved_hour_params])
    if reserved_hour.valid?
      notification = Notification.create(params[:notification])
      if !notification.valid?
        reservation.destroy
        reserved_hour.destroy
      end
    else
      reservation.destroy
    end
  end
end
```

Now I'd like to test database fail cases with RSpec. For example I'd like to simulate database crash during `notification` creating and test if `reservation` and `reserved_hour` destroy successfully. Is there some way to do this without expanding my `create` method for test purposes only? I can simulate crash for all three cases by running `ActiveRecord::Base.remove_connection`, but I have no idea how could I test the case with a single crash.

Comment: Did you sort this out?

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't going to work because all of your `.create` calls will always return *something* (either a saved record or an unsaved record) and your `if` statements will always be true.

Why not use `.create!` (which will raise an error if `create` is unsuccessful) within a [transaction](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html). Something like:

```
def create
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do 
    begin
      Reservation.create!(params[:reservation_params])
      ReservedHour.create!(params[:reserved_hour_params])
      Notification.create!(params[:notification])
    rescue SomeError =>
      # do something with SomeError
    end
  end
end
```

That way, your transactions will be rolled back if you have an error and you don't have to do all that `.destroy` business.

Comment: Okay, my fault, that was just an example, my real code looks different (I edited my post). But that's not my core problem anyway - I'd like to simulate crash of one and only one database action - and I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Why don't you just pass in bad params for one model to your test and then do `expect{whatever}.to raise_error(SomeError)`? I still think your code could be more concise. All those `if`s, `valid?`s and `destroy`s aren't really necessary.